# What strategies are there for handling combinations of values not seen in the training data in a regression problem

Tags: regression, machine-learning, deep-learning, prediction, boosting

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I can't see anything quite like it.

I am trying to make predictions on a data set (prices) based on data which include dates (say, a classic house price regression problem with historical sale prices and their dates).

I can see that the data is somewhat cyclical (ie house prices have monthly cycles) and also there is a yearly trend underneath this, though relatively minor compares to the effects of other parameters (size, location, etc).

My training data consists of, say, data for 2016 and the first half of 2017. What strategies can I use for predicting the second half of 2017? Let's assume I am model agnostic, so can choose a model (adaptive trees, linear regression, deep net, or whatever) which is best for this kind of problem.

For example, I could enter the month and year separately in the training data making these part of the input data set, but then I would be predicting on combinations that have not been seen before (year 17, months 7-12) in the training data, which might be bad for a tree algorithm (but perhaps ok for a deep net?).

Or perhaps I would be better trying to predict in a time agnostic way (ie remove the time/date information from the training set as it's a relatively small factor, possibly with some sort of corrective adjustment to the training set), then somehow adjust the predictions post-calculation for monthly/yearly trends - but how would I do this in a statistically sound way?